# Implement a regular serie in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Let's assume I have the following table:

```
time| id| value
   1|  1|     1
   3|  1|     1
   1|  2|     2
```

The result of selecting a regular series would be:

```
time| id| value
   1|  1|     1
   2|  1|  Null
   3|  1|     1
   1|  2|     2
   2|  2|  Null
   3|  2|  NUll
```

Normally, I would either just store the`NULL` values or create two additional tables: one holding all times, one table holding all id's and than join.

Problem with the first approach is that the table becomes quite big, because each new id forces me to insert NULL values for all previous times and each new time forces me to insert NULL values for all id's.

Problem with the second approach is that the join takes too long.

My idea is to implement a custom set returning function like the crosstab example in `contrib\tablefunc`.

My question is if I can expect this to be faster.

Comment: I think you are looking for `generate_series()`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I think this don't solve the problem, since it only works for one column. If I'm not mistaken I would generate a series for time and id than join with the original table. This may saves some time cause done in memory but looses time since no index and foreign key relationship is exploited.